# Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, crash-reports

I have an app which performs these basic functions:

1. Retrieving data from server
2. Storing it locally
3. Showing the data stored at local to user

This app works as expected on iPhone device, but when one of the customers tried to use the same build on iPad 1, it crashed for him during the delta sync process.

Below is the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 5FE6808F-D558-41D0-A337-68CE8A4B2300
CrashReporter Key:   7a07cd6cfe292ea9f7daac97190d86f9a503415a
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         pCA Dev [2523]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/87C8E4F9-DD63-44AD-9EC2-E9669CCCC519/pCA Dev.app/pCA Dev
Identifier:      pCA Dev
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-05-08 11:47:51.570 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  6

Application Specific Information:
com.dash.pCA failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.350 (user 2.350, system 0.000), 23% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x359380d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ad5674 pthread_mutex_lock + 376
2   CoreData                        0x32b8ad52 -[_PFLock lock] + 18
3   CoreData                        0x32b9a1f2 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 806
4   CoreData                        0x32b98c22 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 598
5   pCA Dev                         0x001697c2 0xce000 + 636866
6   pCA Dev                         0x001698a2 0xce000 + 637090
7   pCA Dev                         0x00219f4e 0xce000 + 1359694
8   pCA Dev                         0x0010445c 0xce000 + 222300
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x33c4fc52 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5ae8a _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 190
11  CoreFoundation                  0x358952a6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1262
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3581849e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
13  CoreFoundation                  0x35818366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
14  GraphicsServices                0x335b3432 GSEventRunModal + 130
15  UIKit                           0x32ff0cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
16  pCA Dev                         0x000cfdb0 0xce000 + 7600
17  pCA Dev                         0x000cfd40 0xce000 + 7488

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x359283a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5bea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5bbc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35928004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x359281fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x358963ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35895124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3581849e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35818366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x3755ec9c RunWebThread(void*) + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ae172e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ae15e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35928004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x359281fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x358963ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35895124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3581849e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35818366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x34c5dbb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x34c5da7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x34cf158a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ae172e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ae15e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35938570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3589a63a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ae172e _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ae15e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35928004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x359281fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x358963ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35895124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3581849e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35818366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x375880d2 WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 122
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ae172e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x34ae15e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: NSManagedObjectContext Queue
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35928054 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5c47e _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$up + 6
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5a65e _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 82
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5a5dc dispatch_barrier_sync_f$VARIANT$up + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5a238 dispatch_sync_f$VARIANT$up + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5a8ee _dispatch_sync_slow + 46
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5a8ae dispatch_sync$VARIANT$up + 18
7   pCA Dev                         0x000d0b88 0xce000 + 11144
8   Foundation                      0x34cdc4f8 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 12
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3588e540 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3581a090 _CFXNotificationPost + 1400
11  Foundation                      0x34c503e4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 60
12  CoreData                        0x32c0dda8 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _didSaveChanges] + 2600
13  CoreData                        0x32c02718 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1692
14  pCA Dev                         0x0010b86c 0xce000 + 252012
15  pCA Dev                         0x001046b6 0xce000 + 222902
16  CoreData                        0x32c0c48e developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform_privateasync + 62
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5aca4 _dispatch_queue_drain + 268
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5ab12 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 30
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x33c5b784 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 208
20  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34adbdf4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
21  libsystem_c.dylib               0x34adbcc8 start_wqthread + 0

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
   0xce000 -   0x236fff +pCA Dev armv7  <76ad4f5bc8d3354d97c9e2de37740dc8> /var/mobile/Applications/87C8E4F9-DD63-44AD-9EC2-E9669CCCC519/pCA Dev.app/pCA Dev
0x2fecd000 - 0x2feeefff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x304e2000 - 0x304e8fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x305e6000 - 0x305fafff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3064e000 - 0x3072dfff  RawCamera armv7  <293f818ba6533dceae8b900b6ed3c887> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x3078c000 - 0x307d8fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x307fa000 - 0x30832fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x30833000 - 0x3085ffff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x30dfa000 - 0x30e4bfff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30ebc000 - 0x30ebcfff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x30ebd000 - 0x30ed3fff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30ed4000 - 0x30ee9fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30f6f000 - 0x30f89fff  CoreServicesInternal armv7  <cccdb5638b17398f8082542c1b3c8cf6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x311a6000 - 0x311c3fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3133d000 - 0x31403fff  GLEngine armv7  <6617f2b4ee283469a5595129889ff049> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x314f3000 - 0x314f3fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31575000 - 0x3164cfff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3164d000 - 0x3166dfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3166e000 - 0x316a9fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x316ce000 - 0x316d0fff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <808518e0fbf539af8489f028ca5198c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x31917000 - 0x31924fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x31930000 - 0x31930fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x31937000 - 0x31950fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x31951000 - 0x31a20fff  IMGSGX535GLDriver armv7  <fe4f330b9a433322844a0d87410b68f7> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver
0x31b22000 - 0x32066fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x32067000 - 0x3206afff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3206b000 - 0x3207cfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3207d000 - 0x32082fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x320b1000 - 0x320d5fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x320d6000 - 0x32139fff  IMCore armv7  <046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x32153000 - 0x32155fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x32164000 - 0x321a7fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x321a8000 - 0x32517fff  TextInput armv7  <8d7f24642c7634cc8e3a6e65f1dcd98e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x32532000 - 0x32536fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3253c000 - 0x32595fff  IMAVCore armv7  <ce90304da959333d81a64171a6ac3ae8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x32596000 - 0x3259cfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x326a3000 - 0x326a6fff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x326b0000 - 0x326b4fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x32712000 - 0x32757fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x32758000 - 0x32764fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32769000 - 0x3276ffff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x327a7000 - 0x327b1fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x329d7000 - 0x329d8fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x329e7000 - 0x32ad8fff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32ad9000 - 0x32aeafff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x32b3b000 - 0x32b51fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x32b82000 - 0x32d28fff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32d29000 - 0x32d38fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32d39000 - 0x32d3efff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <dc11c5c2cbe73a6288a6094ebf5de673> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32d3f000 - 0x32d44fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x32d4a000 - 0x32e19fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <49607ffe4ee9389494285a213e392924> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x32e1a000 - 0x32e30fff  VoiceServices armv7  <c5b98e94eff33bf49006ff157c819987> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x32f7c000 - 0x32f80fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x32fbd000 - 0x32fbefff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32fbf000 - 0x33461fff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x334dd000 - 0x335a3fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x335af000 - 0x335b9fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x335f3000 - 0x33672fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x33717000 - 0x33717fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3375b000 - 0x3376afff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x33771000 - 0x33774fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x33775000 - 0x3378bfff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x33794000 - 0x337a0fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x337a1000 - 0x337d6fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x337f2000 - 0x33811fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33812000 - 0x33937fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33b30000 - 0x33b35fff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <3c1cc3175c403ace8fcbd3826bd43807> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x33b8b000 - 0x33bd5fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x33bfc000 - 0x33c38fff  IMFoundation armv7  <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x33c4f000 - 0x33c65fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x33c66000 - 0x33cd6fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x33cd7000 - 0x33cdbfff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x33dcf000 - 0x33e0bfff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x33e4b000 - 0x33e5dfff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <50ea319aaeb7307e92719980dd4b2953> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x33e80000 - 0x34141fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34230000 - 0x3423ffff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3425b000 - 0x3425bfff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3425c000 - 0x343a1fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x343a2000 - 0x343adfff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x343ae000 - 0x343f7fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x344c2000 - 0x34539fff  CorePDF armv7  <e7ff2b22ce603a84b7d8a7540b403490> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/CorePDF
0x34593000 - 0x34663fff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x34798000 - 0x348f7fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <06a0a1ee488030169bdfab11fc8d2c5c> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x34a63000 - 0x34a64fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x34ad3000 - 0x34b5ffff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x34b73000 - 0x34b74fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x34ba6000 - 0x34ba9fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x34c4d000 - 0x34dcbfff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34edd000 - 0x34ee9fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x34f06000 - 0x34f09fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x34f0a000 - 0x350eefff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3512a000 - 0x35131fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x35135000 - 0x35175fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x3517c000 - 0x351c4fff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x35200000 - 0x3524efff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x352d2000 - 0x352d8fff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x352f3000 - 0x352f4fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x352f5000 - 0x35308fff  AssistantServices armv7  <4a0843742f363a8885b8db13b44ae256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x35309000 - 0x3531cfff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <3f4596cbe1b13fdcb427d87de21df3f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x3531f000 - 0x35369fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3538b000 - 0x35717fff  OfficeImport armv7  <052fc3c6bc543622b6ac72a311fd8e4c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OfficeImport.framework/OfficeImport
0x35718000 - 0x35719fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3575e000 - 0x3579cfff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x357ba000 - 0x357c0fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x357c1000 - 0x357f8fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x35809000 - 0x35920fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35927000 - 0x3593dfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3593e000 - 0x35953fff  libQLCharts.dylib armv7  <efd608d56ceb384f93eea8d5846d76b7> /usr/lib/libQLCharts.dylib
0x35a11000 - 0x35abbfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x35d58000 - 0x35d7dfff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x35d83000 - 0x35dc2fff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x35ece000 - 0x35ed8fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x35f06000 - 0x35ff4fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x35ff7000 - 0x35ffbfff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x361fc000 - 0x363adfff  libCMaps.A.dylib armv7  <88d1ba22553c3069bbb807f777ad5bb0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMaps.A.dylib
0x363ca000 - 0x363cafff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x363cb000 - 0x363cefff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x364f7000 - 0x36540fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x36541000 - 0x3668afff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x36748000 - 0x36749fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3679f000 - 0x367f7fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x36811000 - 0x368befff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x36a20000 - 0x36a64fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x36a88000 - 0x36aabfff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36aac000 - 0x36ab0fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x36ab1000 - 0x36ab1fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x36b03000 - 0x36b07fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x36b5f000 - 0x36bd8fff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x36bdb000 - 0x36d98fff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x36ee7000 - 0x36f38fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x37440000 - 0x37442fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x374b5000 - 0x37c74fff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x37cb6000 - 0x37cf3fff  FTServices armv7  <3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x37e0c000 - 0x37e14fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x37e46000 - 0x37e4ffff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x37e57000 - 0x37e5ffff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x37e60000 - 0x37f38fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x37f39000 - 0x37f39fff  libCGVolute.A.dylib armv7  <f63e81c95d5932e3a6b6ab3da37d8302> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGVolute.A.dylib
0x37f5e000 - 0x37f65fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
```

**Problem is-**

> generally when an app crashes, in crash log it appropriately denotes
>   which thread crashed, but here it is not denoting any such thread, in
>   place it is denoting the highlighted thread.

Please suggest how can I analyze this crash log?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your app just ate bad food (0x8badf00d)! That means the watchdog killed your app because it failed to get ready or resume in time as you can see from the Application Specific Information in your crash log.

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html) says that:

> The exception code 0x8badf00d indicates that an application has been terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events. One common cause of this is doing synchronous networking on the main thread. Whatever operation is on Thread 0: needs to be moved to a background thread, or processed differently, so that it does not block the main thread.

In your case, you are probably doing something time expensive in your `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method which should complete in ~5-6 seconds. Try to use `GCD` or `NSOperationQueue` to move part of your code in a background thread.

Comment: thanx for your useful answer :-)... one more small query: Since it is working fine on iPhone 4 but crashing on iPad 1, so can I consider it to be related to limited resources (processor speed, RAM) on iPad 1 device?

Comment: I don't think it is safe to assume it is related only to the device limited resources (after all, it's hard without seeing a single line of code). Your code may be hanging because of a network error (in that case it would be device independent) or while processing the data. In any case there is a high chance that both cases can be handled on a background queue ;-)